# Generated a Maven Web Application Structure but cant import this into Eclipse IDE .

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2

I am new to Maven .
I am using Maven to build a Web Application Struture .

I have issued this below comand , as a  result it generated ( Please refer to the screen shot )

[image]

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong.core -DartifactId=mkyongweb-core -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false

Now my question is when i tried to import this generated Project into Eclipse IDE through Existing Projects into Workspace Option , it displays No projects are found to import

Please tell me how to resolve this issue .

Thank you very much and Advance New Year Wishes to all .

Comment: Are you using the import option "Maven/Existing Maven Projects" instead of "Java/Existing Projects into Workspace"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is when i tried to import this generated Project into Eclipse IDE
>   through Existing Projects into Workspace Option , it
>   displays No projects are found to import

Not surprising, since it is a maven project and not an existing Eclipse project.

There are two ways to `import this` into Eclipse IDE.

Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (as suggested by @Neevek).  This will generate the `.project` and `.classpath` files, which makes it an Eclipse project.

Better still, ensure you have the [M2E](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) Eclipse Plugin installed.  In this case, you can skip the step above and simply choose `Import as Maven project...`

It is not a good idea to do both - maven eclipse plugin and m2e don't work well together.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to execute the following command to make your web application project "eclipse aware":

`mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Comment: And make sure you have m2eclipse installed into your Eclipse environment.

Comment: Thanks i have solved it by importing Maven Eclipse Plugins and from there on creating New Project from there .